# javafx project set following exception no main class or failed to launch jvm

Tags: javafx

I was made Stand-Alone project.
I used java 8 and netbeans, Finally I have .exe file.

In some PC it work correctly but in other PC it not work properly. Give following error

exception no main class or failed to launch jvm

Comment: Make sure the other PC have Java installed on them.

Comment: Yes, in other PC already installed Java , but what is the problem?